# Change the scrolling recognition to be more vertically strict?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, tableview

My application consists of multiple pages by scrolling horizontally - done by having 2 swipe gesture recognizers over the whole ViewController. On every page I have a ViewTable with items that scroll vertically.

Unless I do a perfect horizontal swipe, the TableView takes over the recognition and does a slight vertical scroll on the table rows.

How do it change the scrolling recognition angle for TableView? Because the table's vertical scrolling is responding from touches around 10º ~ 170º. Whereas I'd like them to be 45º for each direction. How do I narrow that angle? So that my main left/right pages respond easier without having to try to do a perfect horizontal swipe.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really made such a gesture but this is how I think this can be achieved. This is similar to ViewPager on Android. You can use a normal Gesture Recognizer over UITableView, calculate how much x and y displacements are there and then decide whether you want to handle the horizontal scroll yourself by shifting the page or pass the control down to UITableView.

But if you keep your Gesture Recognizer below UITableView, you will never get the control to act upon the gesture unless UITableView passes down to you.